# Move From Legacy to UEFI

Tags: bios, installation, fedora, uefi, legacy

I recently installed Fedora 39 on my system, but I only later realized that I did so in Legacy BIOS mode. Now, I'd like to switch to UEFI boot mode without having to reinstall the entire system. Is there any way to achieve this safely and reliably?

Comment: Typically you'd install Grub for UEFI.

Comment: ... and, of course, you need to have an ESP (EFI System Partition), a small FAT32 formatted partition that, if not there already - created by the installer - you'll have to carve a spec for and create it manually.

Comment: Thanks , There were 2 partions in my SSD 1) filesystem 1.1GB Ext4 2)fedora-localhost-live 240gb btrfs and I created 3rd 3) EFI 256mb FAT32. how can I re install grub for UEFI

Comment: Googling shows many relevant results. Where are you stuck exactly? You're supposed to do your own research before asking. In the first comment I hinted about what to look for. Here one result: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/grub2-bootloader/

Comment: I know  also I tried this site but it's grub configuring sdb (secondary HDD drive ) as an efi drive not SSD

Comment: If so either adjust the drive boot order at UEFI > Boot menu or make sure you install the bootloader where you want it. In any case this isn't a forum, it's a Q&A site. Comments aren't intended to have a forum like discussion.

Comment: No, just waiting for a package with nothing better to do than steer newbies to the right path :) And comments AREN'T answers, that's one of the differences I alluded to previously. You can (and in this case definitely should) [edit] your question anytime and actually describe what you tried and what the results were. That way somebody might be tempted to post a specific answer.